# Change dataframe row names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, rename

I have a df which looks like:

```
BBG.LON.123.S_CAR_ADJ_DPS    343.94325
BBG.LON.436.S_CAR_ADJ_DPS    236.51530
```

I am trying to rename the row names (removing the '_CAR_ADJ_DPS' element of each row name and rename the column 'id' so my resulting df looks like:

```
           id
BBG.LON.123.S   343.94325
BBG.LON.436.S   236.51530
```

I have tried using the following line without success:

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(np.unique([row.split('_')[0] for row in df.rows]), name='id'))
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
print (df)
                                   a
BBG.LON.123.S_CAR_ADJ_DPS  343.94325
BBG.LON.436.S_CAR_ADJ_DPS  236.51530

df.index = df.index.str.split('_').str[0]
df = df.rename_axis('id')
#if use pandas bellow 0.18.0
#df.index.name = 'id'

print (df)
                       a
id                      
BBG.LON.123.S  343.94325
BBG.LON.436.S  236.51530
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also be interested in [str.extract](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#extracting-substrings) to pull out the entries as columns:

```
In [11]: df[0].str.extract('(?P<A>.*)\.(?P<B>.*)\.(?P<C>\d+)\.(?P<D>.)_.*', expand=True)
Out[11]:
     A    B    C  D
0  BBG  LON  123  S
1  BBG  LON  436  S
```